# Is there a decoration to write segment length on a TikZ path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I am drawing a closed path and what I want is to right each segments length either on or next to the path segment. Manually this is a tedious job, but it would work like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \path[spath/save=test] (0mm,0mm)
        -| ++(10mm,20mm)node[sloped,pos=0.25]{10mm}node[sloped,pos=0.75]{20mm}
        -| ++(15mm,10mm)node[sloped,pos=0.25]{15mm}node[sloped,pos=0.75]{10mm}
        -| ++(-20mm,15mm)node[sloped,pos=0.25]{20mm}node[sloped,pos=0.75]{15mm}
        -- ++(-5mm,0mm)node[sloped,pos=0.5]{5mm}
        ;
        \draw[spath/use=test,orange,thick] [spath/transform={test}{xscale=-1}, spath/use={test, reverse, move, weld}] -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now how to automate this?

And bonus question: How to apply it to the transformed path as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the question can be answered with the `show path construction` decoration which is contained in the `decorations.pathreplacing` library. It can probably be generalized to curved segments. However, I do not know how to use this with `spath3`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[measure straight/.style={
        decoration={show path construction, 
            lineto code={
                \path let \p1=($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
                \n1={scalar(sqrt((\x1)*(\x1)+(\y1)*(\y1))/1mm)} 
                in 
                 (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
                 node[midway,sloped]{\pgfmathparse{\n1}%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult mm} 
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            }},decorate
    }]
        
        \draw[postaction=measure straight] (0mm,0mm)
        -| ++(10mm,20mm)
        -| ++(15mm,10mm)
        -| ++(-20mm,15mm)
        -- ++(-5mm,0mm)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for all the comments! This is a version with `closepath`, as suggested, and which avoids the "dimension too large" problem, as pointed out below. Additionally it also does curves. Probably `markings` can also be used for the straight segments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[measure segments/.style={
        decoration={show path construction, 
            lineto code={
                \path let \p1=($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
                in 
                 (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
                 node[midway,sloped]{%
                    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
                    \pgfmathparse{scalar(sqrt((\x1)*(\x1)+(\y1)*(\y1))/1mm)}%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult mm} 
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \path[decorate,{decoration={markings,
                    mark=at position 0.5 with {%
                        \node[transform shape]{\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
                            \pgfmathparse{scalar(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/1mm)}%
                            \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult mm}
                            ;}
                    }}] 
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                .. (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \path let \p1=($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
                in 
                 (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) 
                 node[midway,sloped]{%
                    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
                    \pgfmathparse{scalar(sqrt((\x1)*(\x1)+(\y1)*(\y1))/1mm)}%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult mm} 
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            }},decorate
    }]
        
        \draw[postaction=measure segments] (0mm,0mm)
        -| ++(10mm,20mm)
        -| ++(15mm,10mm)
        -| ++(-20mm,15mm)
        -- ++(-5mm,0mm)
        -| ++(-20mm,150mm)
        to[out=90,in=90] ++ (40mm,0)
        to[out=-90,in=180] ++ (40mm,40mm)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also add `closepath code`

Comment: You could also add `auto=right` option

Comment: Indeed I think you can just add the decoration to the whole path. The solution is great in general, but it doesn't work with large dimensions. Add `-| ++(-20mm,150mm)` in between and it will give an error and show `0mm`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I believe that I could fix the large dimension issue.